# Unable to get action filter to fire

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

*Code examples are simplified to focus on the important bits.*

I have three MVC applications, one of which runs at `https://localhost/App/` and the other two run underneath it (`https://localhost/App/App1/` and `https://localhost/App/App2/`).  Up until now, I've been authorizing users using an attribute that derives from `ActionFilterAttribute`, and it's worked beautifully.  The working attribute looks like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class EntitleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string PermissionName { get; private set; }

    public EntitleAttribute(string permissionName = null)
    {
        PermissionName = permissionName;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        bool hasPermission = IsAccessibleInCurrentContext();
        if (!hasPermission)
        {
            // If the user does not have rights on this action, return a 401.
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I've recently converted over to using Ninject, and I'm trying to convert this over to an Action+Filter setup so that I can inject into the filter.  So now, in order to declare the authorization a user needs to access an action, I have an attribute set up like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class EntitleAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string PermissionName { get; private set; }

    public EntitleAttribute(string permissionName = null)
    {
        PermissionName = permissionName;
    }
}
```

And I have a filter set up like this:

```
public class EntitleFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly string _permissionName;

    public EntitleFilter(string permissionName)
    {
        _permissionName = permissionName;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        bool hasPermission = IsAccessibleInCurrentContext();
        if (!hasPermission)
        {
            // If the user does not have rights on this action, return a 401.
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // Nothing.
    }
}
```

I set up the dependency injection in a `NinjectModule` like so:

```
// Bind authorization handling.
this.BindFilter<EntitleFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0)
    .WhenControllerHas<EntitleAttribute>()
    .WithConstructorArgumentFromControllerAttribute<EntitleAttribute>("permissionName", attr => attr.PermissionName);
this.BindFilter<EntitleFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
    .WhenActionMethodHas<EntitleAttribute>()
    .WithConstructorArgumentFromActionAttribute<EntitleAttribute>("permissionName", attr => attr.PermissionName);
```

When I'm running `App`, everything works great - the `OnActionExecuting` method gets hit on every call.  However, the method never gets called in `App1` or `App2`, even after an `iisreset`.  The filter setup doesn't seem to get hit on first run for `App` or `App1`, either, which seems odd.

The setup is the same for each app, all using common classes.  The `HomeController` in each app has the `EntitleAttribute` on the controller and not the `Index` action, so that's consistent across.

I've tried using AuthorizationAttribute and IAuthorizationFilter as well, with the same results.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tip: If you are doing authorization then you should implement IAuthorizationFilter not IActionFilter.

Comment: @epignosisx:  I had tried using that as well, and it worked the same.  There was a reason I didn't like that filter, but I don't remember now; I may go back to it if binding ever works.